# C# Parameter + Overloading

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, constructor-overloading

I'm trying to create a GUI application that makes use of a class called Chameleon.
Within the class, there are three instance variables, Length, Name and Color.  Length is a double, Name and Color are strings.

I need to overload the constructor of Chameleon.  A new Chameleon object can be created: 1. with the length and name,  2. with the name and color, or 3. with the length, name and color specified.  The constructor should place a message with information about the Chameleon that was just created into a public instance variable.

The GUI should allow the user to enter the length (if it is specified the valid length is from 0.1 to 10.2 inches), the name (must not be empty) and the color (if it is specified it must be one of: 'green', 'orange', 'brown', 'black', 'yellow', or 'red').

When the user presses an 'OK' button a Chameleon object is created using only the arguments for which the user has specified a value. After that the public instance variable containing the message must be displayed in a label from the 'OK' button's click procedure.

I have very little experience with GUI applications and I am completely lost here. Any help at all to at least get me started would be much appreciated. Like for starters, how would you overload the constructor and allow it so that three different object can be created: 1. with the length and name,  2. with the name and color, or 3. with the length, name and color specified?

Comment: Do you know how to create a constructor that does just one of those things?  Can you write one or two of them, but just not a third?  If so, which do you not know how to write?  Just write each one as if it were the only one, except, it just won't be.

Comment: As of right now, what I know about constructors is that you can use them to set values to instance variables. Like this:

Comment: Break up the problem.  Don't ask how to do the whole thing.  Try to write just one of those constructors.  Pick one, and implement it.  If you have questions about how to write that one constructor, then ask about that.  Note that you shouldn't ask how to write the whole thing; there are plenty of widely accessible resources on how to create a constructor in C#, but if, after looking through them, you have a problem, ask about that specific problem.  Then do the same for the next two constructors, as if the first one didn't exist at all.

Comment: class Chameleon
    {
        private double length;
        private string name;
        private string color;

        public Chameleon( double lengthValue, string nameValue, string colorValue)
        {
            length = lengthValue;
            name = nameValue;
            color = colorValue;
        }

Comment: Great.  You have one working constructor.  Now attempt to write the next one.

Comment: The other two have to be different in some way I'm assuming, but I'm not sure how else to format that to make it different.

Comment: The other two have one parameter missing, so make a copy and then remove that parameter from it.

Comment: Ok, I've got you. Now I can atleast proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the last thing I need to figure out is how to set the range for length between 0.1 - 10.2, and the range of color must be either green', 'orange', 'brown', 'black', 'yellow', or 'red'.

Comment: I'm assuming I would do the input validation inside the constructor so that it will on assign the values if the conditions are met?

Comment: @user3380103 You have to validate that either in your constructor or in a separate method. Where do you want to do this check? How do you want to return an error?

Comment: The user should never leave the Name section empty, so it should force them to enter something in that textbox. The color must be one of the available choices. If either of these is invalid, I want a messagebox to pop up telling the user to enter valid values. As for the length, I have that figured out.

Comment: @user3380103 So you can either validate it in the constructor or when you receive input before creating the new instance. Either may be preferable depending on how your GUI is set up. ie. `if (validName(name) && validLength(length) && validColor(color)){ Chameleon chameleon = new Chameleon(name, length, color)} else { ...}` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Add your other constructors with the parameters you need, like so:

```
class Chameleon
{

    private double length;
    private string name;
    private string color;

    public Chameleon(string nameValue, double lengthValue, string colorValue)
    {
        name = nameValue;
        length = lengthValue;
        color = colorValue;
    }

    public Chameleon(string nameValue, double lengthValue)
    {
        name = nameValue;
        length = lengthValue;
    }

    public Chameleon(string nameValue, string colorValue)
    {
        name = nameValue;
        color = colorValue;
    }
}
```

Then from the procedure that creates this instance, write it like so:

```
Chameleon chameleon = new Chameleon("SomeName", 1.0);
Chameleon anotherChameleon = new Chameleon("SomeOtherName", "blue");
Chameleon aThirdChameleon = new Chameleon("ChameleonName", 1.0, "blue");
```

Answer (score -2):

You first should create a default constructor. A default constructor would be used when you do not pass any parameters to instantiate your object. The default constructor will use your default values. Then you can create your overloaded constructors. An overloaded constructor will take any number of different parameters that will override the default values.

```
class Chameleon 
{ 
    private double length; 
    private string name; 
    private string color; 

    //default constructor
    public Chameleon()
    {
      length = 2;
      name = "widget";
      color = "blue";
    }

    //Overloaded Constructor
    public Chameleon( double lengthValue, string nameValue, string colorValue)
    { 
        length = lengthValue; 
        name = nameValue; 
        color = colorValue; 
    }
```